# virtualbox gitlab -remote origin does not support the lfs locking api. consider disabling it with

Tags: git, gitlab, x509certificate

I have  a virtualbox centos 8 virtual machine. I could clone my repository from gitlab. Network interface of my virtual machine is **NAT** . When I push my local files to branch. I got following error.

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with: $ git config lfs.https://gitlab.<company-name>/<project>/<project>.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
```

I disable it with upper command as the ouput said and I got following error.

```
batch response: x509 certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I controlled the settings of gitlab, LFS is enabled. Can you help me to overcome this issue because I don't know the source of this error whether network settings of my virtual machine or gitlab settings.
Thanks

Comment: It sounds potentially like two separate issues... the certificate issue sounds like your server's certificate is not trusted by your local computer. Are you able to connect to your virtual machine with **HTTPS** at all? How about **HTTP**?

Comment: I connect with ssh from my localhost